# Shrink Size of AWS Deployment Package

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, devops

Is their any way to shrink size of the deployment package  in python.
I'm using Fbprophet and other liraries by which Lambda max. size limit is exceeding so can we shrink those libraries and deploy .zip to AWS Lambda ??

Answer (score 0):

Lambda Layers sound like what you want - They allow you to have a separate package with all your dependencies which then you can reference in your code.

From their docs:

> Layers let you keep your deployment package small, which makes
>   development easier. You can avoid errors that can occur when you
>   install and package dependencies with your function code. For Node.js,
>   Python, and Ruby functions, you can develop your function code in the
>   Lambda console as long as you keep your deployment package under 3 MB.

For more info Layers see : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html

Comment: With all the depndencies in my code  total size of the package is exceeding 250 MB limit  of Lambda.